# Rust Cargo Build Error. Access is Denied. OS Error 5

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I just installed rust from: https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install
then proceeded to go through this doc to get it started in VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/rust
I'm on the Cargo Build section of it trying to to build my first project. But when I ran the command:
cargo build
I got an error:
error: Access is denied. (os error 5)
I am on cargo  1.72.0 (103a7ff2e 2023-08-15)
I am on rustc 1.72.0 (5680fa18f 2023-08-23)
I'm also getting the exact same error for cargo c, t, b
Also, I've located the rust projects on my D Drive. Should I be in C:\Windows\System32 ?

I tried deleting rust then reinstalling it with my anti-virus disabled, but still got the same problem. How do I get around this?

EDIT: Okay. I just figured it out. It's because I wasn't in the System32 directory, but in VS Code, I am still getting the same error. If i run it from pwsh, It's fine though. weird

Comment: You shouldn't be putting anything in System32. I doubt anyone is going to figure out what's wrong from a single question, so you should probably try chat or asking someone in person.

Comment: You're right about the System32 part. I moved my projects to ~\projects and I dont have the issue anymore. Thanks drew Tate

Answer (score 1):

You may just need to change your permission grants on the PowerShell

Use this command to check your current execution policy

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

It should be **Restricted**

To reset it open Powershell as Admin

Use this command to set the execution policy to **remote Signed** or **unrestricted**, this would allow scripts to be run on the shell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

or

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

You can read more! on the shell policy . But those commands should solve the issue

Comment: Awesome insight. I did not know you could do that. It still didn't work, but no fret, I just changed my projects folder to ~\projects and when I do any cargo command, it runs smoothly. Thanks for the help! I think the issue may be was where I was storing it. Because if I stored in in C:\downloads it ran well there, but if I made a new folder in D drive, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah its possibly , where you where storing it . But I presumed it could be some random access issues. I am happy you where able to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 I had this problem as well and this fixed it for me.

I created an environment variable called PROTOC in its bin folder

I also added in PATH the same bin folder

I had also put the library inside the user profile

After moving from the user profile to a stand-alone directory the issue was still present.
I removed the PROTOC environment variable and the build continued

Hope this helps some people.

Answer (score -1):

Go to folder properties>securities give your user read and write permission

Comment: I get the impression that the solution is the same as in other existing answers. The rest of your post is not exactly better worded or more detailed. In fact it completely lacks any explanation of the problem or why your solution helps. Please make more obvious which additional inisght you are contributing.